# Wrong Output for Limit

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I want to calculate the following limit:

```
Limit[(a2 EllipticTheta[3, -((π (l + d0 g t))/(2 l)), 
    E^(-((d0 π^2 t)/l^2))])/(2 Abs[l]) + (
  a2 EllipticTheta[3, (π (l - d0 g t))/(2 l), 
    E^(-((d0 π^2 t)/l^2))])/(2 Abs[l]) + (
  a1 Sqrt[(d0 t)/l^2]
    EllipticTheta[3, -((d0 g π t)/(2 l)), 
    E^(-((d0 π^2 t)/l^2))])/Sqrt[d0 t], l -> Infinity]
```

Mathematica gives an output of zero. However, if I put g=0; before using Limit, the output is not zero anymore! Also when I run the following piece of code:

```
a1 = 1;
a2 = 1;
g = 1.5;
d0 = 1;
t = 0.001;
Plot[(a2 EllipticTheta[3, -((π (l + d0 g t))/(2 l)), 
    E^(-((d0 π^2 t)/l^2))])/(2 Abs[l]) + (
  a2 EllipticTheta[3, (π (l - d0 g t))/(2 l), 
    E^(-((d0 π^2 t)/l^2))])/(2 Abs[l]) + (
  a1 Sqrt[(d0 t)/l^2]
    EllipticTheta[3, -((d0 g π t)/(2 l)), 
    E^(-((d0 π^2 t)/l^2))])/Sqrt[d0 t], {l, 100, 1000}]
```

The output is not zero and doesn't go to zero as `l` increases. Can any one explain why Mathematica gives an incorrect output here? Can anyone help me to get the correct outcome of the Limit function?

Comment: Are you certain it's wrong? If you check the limits of `EllipticTheta` function arguments, you see all values of `EllipticTheta` in your equation converging to zero. (Consider `Limit[EllipticTheta[3, Pi/2, x], x -> 1, Direction -> 1]` and friends.) Numerics of `Plot` behaving the way they do is an entirely different question.

Comment: Yes I am. Because if you put g=0; the output of Limit function is not zero anymore @kirma

Comment: Hmm, interesting. This is not the case in your plot, though. I have to leave this, be it numerics or symbolics, to others.

Comment: I think `Limit` should generate conditions for its output if you add `GenerateConditions -> True` option to it - but it doesn't.

Comment: Where did this expression come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the definition of [`EllipticTheta`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EllipticTheta) from the documentation:

$$\vartheta _3(u,q)=1+2 \sum _n^{\infty } q^{n^2} \cos (2 n u)$$

it is clear that $\vartheta_3(0, 1)$ diverges. Your problematic term is:

```
term = EllipticTheta[3, -((d0 g π t)/(2 l)), E^(-((d0 π^2 t)/l^2))]
```

> EllipticTheta[3, -((d0 g π t)/(2 l)), E^(-((d0 π^2 t)/l^2))]

Let $l = 1/s$ and replace the arguments with the small $s$ approximations:

```
term /. l->1/Series[s, {s, 0, 1}] //TeXForm
```

> $\vartheta _3\left(-\frac{1}{2} s (\pi  \operatorname{d0} g t)+O\left(s^2\right),1-\pi ^2 \operatorname{d0} s^2
>    t+O\left(s^3\right)\right)$

which is of the form:

```
EllipticTheta[3, -b s, 1 - a s^2]
```

When $b=0$, Mathematica knows about the asymptotic behavior of this function as $s \to 0$:

```
Assuming[a>0, Series[EllipticTheta[3, 0, 1 - a s^2], {s, 0, 0}]] //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{\sqrt{\pi } (-1)^{\left\lfloor -\frac{\arg (s)}{\pi }\right\rfloor } e^{-i \pi  \left\lfloor
>    \frac{3}{4}-\frac{\arg \left(-a s^2\right)}{2 \pi }\right\rfloor }}{\sqrt{a} s}$

However, when the second argument also depends on $s$, there appears to be a bug:

```
Series[EllipticTheta[3, -b s, 1 - a s^2], {s, 0, 0}, Assumptions->a>0] //TeXForm
```

> $\vartheta _3(0,1)+O\left(s^1\right)$

There is an internal function that is designed to handle [`EllipticTheta`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EllipticTheta) series, but it doesn't seem to be used. We can work around the above issue by using it directly. First, let's reproduce the known result above:

```
Assuming[a>0, System`SeriesDump`ThetaFunction[3, 0, 1-a s^2, s, 0, 0]] //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{\sqrt{\pi } (-1)^{\left\lfloor -\frac{\arg (s)}{\pi }\right\rfloor } e^{-i \pi  \left\lfloor
>    \frac{3}{4}-\frac{\arg \left(-a s^2\right)}{2 \pi }\right\rfloor }}{\sqrt{a} s}$

Now, let's try it on the second example:

```
series = Assuming[
    a>0 && b>0,
    System`SeriesDump`ThetaFunction[3, -b s, 1-a s^2, s, 0, 0]
];
series //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{\sqrt{\pi } (-1)^{\left\lfloor -\frac{\arg (s)}{\pi }\right\rfloor } \exp \left(b^2 s^2
>    \left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{a s^2}\right)-i \pi  \left\lfloor \frac{3}{4}-\frac{\arg \left(-a s^2\right)}{2
>    \pi }\right\rfloor \right)}{\sqrt{a} s}$

Much better! Now, recall that the above [`EllipticTheta`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EllipticTheta) term comes with a prefactor of $\sqrt{\frac{1}{l^2}}$, or equivalently $\sqrt{s^2}$, so we want the limit of `s series` as $s \to 0$. Hence:

```
lim[a_, b_] = Assuming[
    a>0 && b>0 && s>0,
    Limit[Simplify[s series], s -> 0]
];
lim[a, b] //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{\sqrt{\pi } e^{-\frac{b^2}{a}}}{\sqrt{a}}$

Summarizing, we have the limit:

$$\underset{s\to 0}{\text{lim}}\,s \vartheta _3(-b s,1-a s^2)=\frac{e^{-\frac{b^2}{a}} \sqrt{\pi
   }}{\sqrt{a}}$$

Now, the only nonzero term in the limit $s \to 0$ is then:

```
((a1 Sqrt[(d0 t)/l^2] EllipticTheta[3,-((d0 g π t)/(2 l)),E^(-((d0 π^2 t)/l^2))])/Sqrt[d0 t])
```

which takes the form:

```
c s EllipticTheta[3, -b s, 1 - a s^2]
```

where:

```
c = a1;
a = d0 π^2 t
b = d0 g π t/2
```

Hence, the symbolic limit is:

```
res = a1 lim[d0 π^2 t, d0 g π t/2];
res //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{\operatorname{a1} e^{-\frac{1}{4} \operatorname{d0} g^2 t}}{\sqrt{\pi } \sqrt{\operatorname{d0} t}}$

Let's check:

```
v = res /. {a1 -> 1, d0 -> 1, g -> 3/2, t -> 1/1000};
v //TeXForm
N[v, 20]
```

> $\frac{10 \sqrt{\frac{10}{\pi }}}{e^{9/16000}}$
>
> 17.831208285385305584

in agreement with Bob's answer.

Comment: I think ou made a mistake at the line before "Lets check"

Answer (score 0):

Machine precision cannot produce meaningful results. Use [`arbitrary precision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ArbitraryPrecisionNumbers.html) and start with exact values for constants.

```
a1 = 1;
a2 = 1;
g = 3/2;
d0 = 1;
t = 10^-3;

f[l_] = (a2 EllipticTheta[3, -((π (l + d0 g t))/(2 l)), 
        E^(-((d0 π^2 t)/l^2))])/(2 Abs[l]) + (a2 EllipticTheta[
        3, (π (l - d0 g t))/(2 l), E^(-((d0 π^2 t)/l^2))])/(2 Abs[
        l]) + (a1 Sqrt[(d0 t)/l^2] EllipticTheta[3, -((d0 g π t)/(2 l)), 
        E^(-((d0 π^2 t)/l^2))])/Sqrt[d0 t] // Simplify[#, l > 0] &;
```

Accurate calculations are very slow.

```
AbsoluteTiming[(N[f[#], 12] // Chop) & /@ {100, 200, 500, 750, 1000}]

(* {296.342, {17.8312082854, 17.8312082854, 17.8312082854, 17.8312082854, 
  17.8312082854}} *)
```

From the documentation, [`EllipticTheta`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EllipticTheta.html) is only defined **inside** the unit disk for its third argument.

```
Cases[f[l], EllipticTheta[3, u_, q_] :> Limit[q, l -> Infinity], Infinity]

(* {1, 1, 1} *)
```

In the `Limit` you are trying to evaluate each `EllipticTheta` **on** the unit circle. I suspect that this is what is causing the problem with the `Limit`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how can I find the limit without giving numbers to parameters?

Comment: sorry, I cannot understand what does your code do.  What is the output {1,1,1} ?

Comment: @HolgerMate - the `{1,1,1}` indicates the the third argument of each of the `EllipticTheta`s goes to `1` in the `Limit`, i.e., the `Limit` is trying to evaluate the `EllipticTheta`s where they are not defined and gets confused in the process.

Comment: So what is the real result for the limit?

Comment: @HolgerMate - I have no reason to believe that the general symbolic limit exists. Why do you think that one does? You are probably restricted to specific numeric cases.

Comment: because we are calculating the limit of EllipticTheta s when their third argument goes to 1, but they are not equal to 1.

Comment: Would u also tell me what are 
{296.342, {17.8312082854, 17.8312082854, 17.8312082854, 17.8312082854, 
  17.8312082854}}

Comment: `{17.8312082854, ... , 17.8312082854}` is the result of evaluating `f` for arguments `{100, 200, 500, 750, 1000}`, The values are identical, so `f` converged to the numeric limit `17.8312082854` and stayed constant for sampled values over the range `{100, 1000}` to within displayed precision. The `296.342` is the time in seconds to do the five calculations. See documentation for [`AbsoluteTiming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsoluteTiming.html), [`Map (/@)`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html), [`Chop`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Chop.html).

Comment: Although `Sin[x] / x` is isn't defined at 0, it has a limit for it. In that regard I'm a bit suspicious on the reasoning on `EllipticTheta`.